# Need help with wiring a light fixture

Tags: electrical

Could someone help me wire this light fixture? I've attached two pictures for reference. The outlet box contains three wire cables: two 2-wire cables and one 3-wire cable. Only one of the cables is live. There was a fan installed but I decided to remove it for a light. The new light fixture has two black wires and two white wires (+ ground). I'm not an electrician by any means. If someone can help me out, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks,
slkern

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What wires are in the switch box that controlled the old fan and light?

Comment: Also, your description would indicate that there should be 7 wires from those three cables (excluding grounds), but only five wires are showing in your picture.

Comment: Can you get us a close-up view of the insides of the light box?

Comment: It's been a long time since the fan was taken off but the red was attached to the fan for sure. I didn't take any of the black or white wires apart other than to pull the fan wires out of the wire nuts. And I guess it looks that way in the picture, but there are three black wires and three whites twisted together there.

Comment: Yeah, I'll upload another picture. One sec.

Comment: Did you forget to tell us that there are two other light fixtures controlled by the same switch that controlled lights on the fan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new fixture will be attached by the following: two black wires from the new fixture will be connected to the red wire from the ceiling box.  The two white wires from the new fixture will go to the whites in the box. Grounds will go to the bare wire.  P.

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for the reply! I uploaded a new picture with more detail. I found out where the wires come and go. Is your solution still good?

Comment: Blacks go together, supplying the switch loop and the rest of the circuit.

Comment: Still the same.